# Can RPM packages be installed into Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I noticed that there is a command - rpm - under Cygwin 1.7. Does that mean RPM packages can be installed into Cygwin?

I tried to install ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3.i686.rpm (see: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/LATEST/) into Cygwin 1.7.13 with the command "install -i ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3.i686.rpm". However, this error message appeared.

I tried to search for the missing libs using the setup.exe of Cygwin. It seems that some of them were not present, such as libc.so.6, libdl.so.2,  libm.so.6,  libnsl.so.1, and  libz.so.1. Where can I get these libs?

```
$ rpm -i ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3.i686.rpm
    error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/perl is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libbz2.so.1 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libdl.so.2 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libm.so.6 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libnsl.so.1 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libpthread.so.0 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    librt.so.1 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libstdc++.so.6 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.5) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    libz.so.1 is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(Archive::Tar) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(Digest::MD5) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(File::Temp) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(File::stat) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(Getopt::Long) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(Net::FTP) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(Pod::Usage) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(constant) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(strict) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
    perl(warnings) is needed by ncbi-blast-2.2.26+-3
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's visible from the missing files that this RPM is aimed at Linux, and will not work in Windows.

`rpm` support in Cygwin is meant to be used for building your own RPM packages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But you cannot install **arbitrary** RPMs into Cygwin; they must be created specifically for the appropriate arch of Cygwin, and they must have all dependencies as RPMs as well.